# Ansible - Find host matching several variables or group memberships

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to create a playbook that will provision and setup a server and its standby server. The inventory is coming from Red Hat Satellite 6.x/Foreman and the playbook is being kicked off as a call back to Ansible AWX/Tower.

AWX calls the playbook with --limit to the specific server that made the callback. But I am able to access the whole inventory using inventory_hostnames.

The items that will be common between the primary and standby servers, that need to be matched are, foreman.location_id or foreman.location_name, foreman.hostgroup_id or foreman.hostgroup_title, foreman.environment_id or foreman.environment_name. These are also exposed as group memberships to foreman_location_[locationName], foreman_hostgroup_[hostgroupTitle], foreman_environment_[environmentName]. If all of these variables or groups are matched, only the two servers will be returned.

I am able to find servers in each of these groups with something like:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'foreman_location_datacenter,&foreman_environment_production') }}"
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to specify the groups dynamically based on the groups of the current host.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'foreman_location_{{ foreman.location_name | map('trim') }}') }}"
```

I get

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'trim'. String: {{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'foreman_location_{{ foreman.location_name | map('trim')  }}') }}"}
```

And if I remove the 's from around trim I get nothing back.

When I try

```
 - debug:
    msg: "foreman_location_{{ foreman.location_name | map('trim') | list | join }}"
```

I get the correct string back.

EDIT:
I believe I have found a workable solution:

```
- name: Set Facts
  set_fact:
      jer_location: "foreman_location_{{ foreman.location_name | map('trim') | list | join | lower }}"
      jer_hostgroup: "foreman_hostgroup_{{ foreman.hostgroup_title | map('trim') | list | join | lower | replace('/', '_') }}"
      jer_environment: "foreman_environment_{{ foreman.environment_name | map('trim') | list | join | lower }}"

- name: List hosts from variable groups
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', '{{ jer_location }},&{{ jer_hostgroup }},&{{ jer_environment }}') }}"
```

If there is a better one, I would like to hear it.

Thank you in advance,

Jeremy

Comment: Be aware that inside `{{` it's python code, so having nested ones is unlikely to be helpful; what you'd want is `with_inventory_hostnames: "{{ [jer_location, '&'+jer_hostgroup, '&'+jer_environment] }}"`. You can also move the `set_fact:` children to a `vars:` on the `debug:`, and keep those effectively temp variables from leaking into your playbook

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I would pass variables to a module like that. Everything feels much cleaner now.